# PIM focused on conversations and goals, with communications protocol compatibility, for Linux or Android?

Tags: offline, note-taking, crm, communication, personal-information-management

I need software that can help me keep track of what I said and what people said to me. I need to be able to record conversations, bookmark what people said so I can review, keep notes, draft replies, and schedule follow-ups. I basically need personal CRM for essential tasks. Integration with task management and calendars (CardDav/CalDav etc) would be a plus.

I can use it if it runs on Linux or Android, but honestly, if a software is good enough, I would buy a device and carry it around just for this purpose.

Comment: To me, this sounds just like your other question.  How is it different?

Comment: @RohitGupta here I want metadata and communications protocols. CRM (or VRM) features. In the other question, I am asking for voice audio transcription and indexing. I imagine I won't be able to find both functions in one piece of software, but if I'm wrong, that software would be what I am looking for, so please post an answer!